# Recursion Approach for leetcode 2 keys keyboard problem

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/2-keys-keyboard/  using recursion. I initialised 2 variables screen and buffer. screen means count of all the characters on screen and buffer means count of all the characters which were copied on previous step

So function is called like this when we copy -
function(screen,screen)

and paste means -
function(screen+buffer,buffer)

but this is not working Here is the code-

```
def keyboard(screen,buffer, c,n):
    if screen == n:
        return c
    if screen>n:
        return
    if buffer>n:
        return    
  
      
    keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n)
    keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n)

print(keyboard(1,0,0,8))
```

I am getting maximum recursive depth
This is memoized approach

```
    def keyboard(self,screen,buffer,c,n,dp):
        
        large_num = 100000 # larger than possible moves
        
        if dp[screen][buffer] != -1:
            return dp[screen][buffer]
  
        if screen == n:
            return c           

        if screen>n:
            return large_num  

        if buffer>n:
            return large_num  

        if c > n:  
            return large_num
       
        dp[screen][buffer] =  min(self.keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n,dp), self.keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n,dp))
        return dp[screen][buffer]  

    def minSteps(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = [[-1 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]

        return(self.keyboard(1,0,0,n,dp))
```

Comment: If recursion is the issue, use a loop instead.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Your `keyboard` function refers a 'buffer' that does not exist. `NameError: name 'buffer' is not defined`.

Comment: Your recursive call ```keyboard(1, 0, 0, 8)``` will run in infinite loop. As you are adding ```screen + buffer ``` i.e ```keyboard(1 + 0, 0, 0, 8) will``` be called  as ```keyboard(1, 0, 0, 8)```  again and again. And also there's no condition is mentioned to tackle this in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- Need to limit the number of moves (i.e. c value)
- Need to optimize the moves by taking the minimum

**Code**

```
def keyboard(screen,buffer,c,n):
  large_num = 100000 # larger than possible moves

  if screen == n:
    return c           # Found solution

  if screen>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if buffer>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if c > n:  # limit number of moves
    return large_num
  
  # Optimize choice by taking minimum
  return min(keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n), keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n))

print(keyboard(1,0,0,8)) 
# Output: 6
```

**Add Memoization**

```
def keyboard(screen,buffer,c,n, memcache = None):
  if memcache is None:
    memcache = {}
  large_num = 100000 # larger than possible moves

  # Input state as tuple
  state = (screen, buffer, c, n)

  if state in memcache:
    return memcache[state]

  if screen == n:
    return c           # Found solution

  if screen>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if buffer>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if c > n:  # limit number of moves
    return large_num
  
  # Using memoization to cache current value
  # Optimize choice by taking minimum
  memcache[state] = min(keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n), keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n))

  return memcache[state]

print(keyboard(1,0,0,8))
```

**Memoization Using Decorator**

This is equivalent to the previous case, but uses a decorator to allow any function with washable position argument to be memorized,

```
def memoize(f):
    """This automates the previous example where we added a cache.  
       It uses a decorator function to add a cache to any function with
       hashable position arguments
    """
    memo = {}
    def helper(*args):
        if args not in memo:            
            memo[args] = f(*args)
        return memo[args]
    return helper

@memoize
def keyboard(screen,buffer,c,n):

  large_num = 100000 # larger than possible moves

  if screen == n:
    return c           # Found solution

  if screen>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if buffer>n:
    return large_num  # Out of bounds (make moves larger than max possible)

  if c > n:  # limit number of moves
    return large_num
  
  # Using memoization to cache current value
  # Optimize choice by taking minimum
  return min(keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n), keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n))

print(keyboard(1,0,0,8))
```

**Fix to Posters Memoization Code**

Issue was memorization was not over the complete state of input.

- Posted code was using (screen, buffer) as state
- State is actually (screen, buffer, c) (don't need n since it's fixed)

*Fixed Code*

```
class Solver:
  def keyboard(self,screen,buffer,c,n,dp):
    
    large_num = n + 1 # larger than largest possible moves
    
    if screen>n or buffer>n or c > n:
      return large_num 

    if dp[screen][buffer][c] != -1:
      return dp[screen][buffer][c]

    if screen == n:
      dp[screen][buffer][c] = c          
    
    elif buffer == 0:
      dp[screen][buffer][c] = self.keyboard(screen, screen, c+1, n, dp)
    else:
      # screen can not be zero
      # minimum of copy and paste move
      dp[screen][buffer][c] =  min(self.keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n,dp), self.keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n,dp))
      
    return dp[screen][buffer][c]  

  def minSteps(self, n: int) -> int:
    dp = [[[-1 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)] for k in range(n+1)]

    return self.keyboard(1,0,0,n,dp)

s = Solver()
print(s.minSteps(8))
# Output: 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much Can you please help me know what was your approach? How you came to such solution and what was I doing wrong?

Comment: @PratyushNarain--1) Your function calls keyboard twice which represents the two operations that can be performed.  But it doesn't choose which of these operations is better.  The min does that. 2) We know solution should be less than n moves, so we should restrict c to that.  3) We need to return a value that helps us to select the best option (so that's why we return large_num when we run out of bound).

Comment: @PratyushNarain--another way to think about this is as a search algorithm with two moves at each turn (copy or paste).  The idea is to find the sequence of moves that get you to your destination in the minimum number of moves. For copy, my move count will be `keyboard(screen+buffer,buffer,c+1,n)`.  For paste my move count will be `keyboard(screen,screen,c+1,n)`.  I need to select between these two to get the mimum move count i.e. `min(keyboard(screen, ...), keyboard(screen+buffer...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. Can you help me how to approach this problem using memoization? I shall be grateful if u will help me out :)

Comment: @PratyushNarain--Added a couple examples of memoization.  Let me know if there are further questions.

Comment: Thanku sir I have added my memoized approach using matrix.  Can you help me what am I doing wrong? I am getting 10000 as answer insted of 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216671/discussion-between-darrylg-and-pratyush-narain).

Comment: @PratyushNarain--updated answer fixing your code.  Let me know if any questions about it.